# Cancel background script run from any shell

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script I usually keep running in the background; it sets up port forwarding I use for database connections while developing an app whose details are irrelevant at the moment. Because I always want this running, I have it set to start up whenever a new shell opens - it checks if that port is in use and starts forwarding if not.

```bsh
function forward {                                                                   
    if lsof -Pi :55433 -sTCP:LISTEN -t >/dev/null ; then
        echo "redirect already running"
    else
        target=$(~/environment-destination.sh staging)
        ~/forwarder.sh 55433 stuff.rds.amazonaws.com:5432 $target > /dev/null &
        echo "redirect running"                                                   
    fi                                                                           
}
```

What I want to do is to make it possible for another script, run in any shell, to stop this script and free up the port. (Primarily I want this because I occasionally want to set up forwarding to the production instance instead of the staging environment.) I tried saving the `pid` to a file and running `pkill` on it, but this doesn't work - and `pgrep` doesn't find it either. Is there a better approach?

Comment: If your system is controlled by systemd, another option is run the script as a user service.  Read `man systemd.service`, `man systemd.unit`, `man systemd.exec`. It may look intimidating; basically, all you need is a single line `ExecStart=/bin/sh %h/forwarder.sh ...`. Add `Restart=on-failure` if you want. Note that ExecStart takes execve arguments which are _not_ parsed by the shell. Best of all, run a single script there, and put the 2-line logic into it. Here's a well-commented but _complex_sample: https://gist.github.com/kkm000/73bde1ee82c577c84c96ab5d71de44ea (your will be much simpler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Should create a shell script like this :

```
function forward {                                                                   
    if lsof -Pi :55433 -sTCP:LISTEN -t >/dev/null ; then
        echo "redirect already running"
    else
        target=$(~/environment-destination.sh staging)
        ~/forwarder.sh 55433 stuff.rds.amazonaws.com:5432 $target > /dev/null &
        echo $! > /tmp/forward.pid
        echo "redirect running"                                                   
    fi                                                                           
}
```

Then killing your forwarding is done by `kill $(cat /tmp/forward.pid)`

Comment: It's also a good idea to `rm` that file in the script that invokes `kill`.

Comment: That's what I previously tried; it didn't seem to work. I was using `pkill`, I guess that was the only problem. (Grumble Grumble p- prefix inexplicably means *not* pid rather than the reverse Grumble.)